# make: Cleaner way to refer to object files in subdirectories

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've got a simple program that has sources in its root directory and in subdirectories.  I'm using recursive `make` invocations to build the subdirectory objects.  When linking I can use a symbolic name for the objects in the program's root (`${OBJECTS}`) but not for objects in the subdirectories (`*/*.o`).  Is there a cleaner way to refer to the subdirectory object files than what I've written?   I'm using GNU Make 4.1.  Here's the (simplified) top-level Makefile:

```
MAKE    = make
CXX     = g++
CFLAGS  = -O -Wall -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_BSD_SOURCE
LIBS    = 

PROGRAM = program_name

TOPTARGETS := all clean

SUBDIRS := util command device

$(TOPTARGETS): $(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)

.PHONY: $(TOPTARGETS) $(SUBDIRS)

all: $(PROGRAM)

SOURCES := $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.cpp %.h

$(PROGRAM): $(OBJECTS) ${SUBDIRS}
    $(CXX) -o $(PROGRAM) ${OBJECTS} */*.o $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f ${OBJECTS} $(PROGRAM)
```

Comment: After years of training I've come to the conclusion it is best to write all objects down manually into the makefile. Easy to write, easy to read. Using `wildcard` and iterating over subfolder using e.g. `$(shell find ...)` will make for less code, but takes longer to get right than the boring just-do-it solution, and comes with nasty caveats and gotchas. Somewhat useful for generated source where name is unknown, but other than that - run. (Not making this an answer since I hate "you are doing it wrong"-styled answers.)

Comment: @Andreas Honestly, when I write Makefiles I typically list all the objects explicitly.  In this case I've got a lot of sources in a couple of the directories and repeatedly neglected to add them to the Makefile as I created them.  Hence I reckoned I'd write my Makefiles the "proper way" for a change.

Comment: I sympathize. Globbing sources appears like a neat workflow enhancement when forgetting to add them manually. Then you get hurt because of something the globbing caused, and the circle of make-life is starts over.